# android sqlite replace method if new-coming data is null

Tags: android, sqlite

Using REPLACE in sqlite, when the new coming data is null. The original data will be overwritten to null or stay here? 
If overwritten, what can I do to let the original not be null?
EX:
**id| name| num |**  (if id is PK)
**1 | Amy  | 1234 |**

**db.replace(1, Amy, null)**

what's result will be?
**1 | Amy | 1234|**  OR  **1 | Amy | null|**

Answer (score 3):

On a pk match the whole row will be replaced, so **1 | Amy | null|**

Answer (score 1):

before insert /replace you can check orginal data is null or not null then try to replace in this column.